# How to make a settings command [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

I am using `discord.js` to make a settings command for a bot: I need help to make it to where it let you choose if you want it to have a specific event on or off.
I’ve been trying to look for tutorials for the past week and had no luck. it should look like this:

[image]

Example of the command: **!settings blacklist on/off**

Here’s the code I’m trying to make as a settings command:

```
bot.on('message', async message => {

  //1 blacklisted words
  let blacklisted = ['fuck', 'shit,', 'bullshit', 'bitch', 'asshole', 'cunt', 'virgin', 'discord.gg'] //words

  //2 looking for words
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) { // loops through the blacklisted list
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) // checks casesensitive words
      foundInText = true;
  }

  //3 deletes and send message
  if (foundInText) {
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:').then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
  }
});
```

I dont expect a spoon feed or something, maybe a little example for me to tinker with or a link to do this. Thank you if your here to help me. Id appricate that.

Comment: What are you asking here? Do you want the whole command to be able to be toggled on/off or do you want some of the words to be flagged/unflagged?

Comment: @T.Dirks to become toggled on/off. Heres an example: !settings blacklist on/off

Comment: Why don't you create a command that interacts with the database where you can create a table with the settings and GuildName?

Comment: @KoenHollander I am new to discord.js and i need a little asistance. Either spoonfeed, guide me, or give me a link.

Comment: Maybe https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp will help, otherwist I advise you to learn a little bit more about NodeJS/MySQL/Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```js
    const blacklist = ['word1', 'word2']; //define the words array
    //check if the message contain atleast one blacklisted word
    if (blacklist.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)){
    //your code
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed code (sorry for that last one):

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
      var message1 = message.content.toLowerCase();

      if (message1.includes('offensiveword1')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword2')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword3')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword4')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword5')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword6')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword7')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
      if (message1.includes('offensiveword8')) {
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send('Hey! That word is not allowed!! :rage:')
          .then(message => message.delete(5000));
      }
```

Comment: I fail to see how this solves any of OP's questions. To me it just looks like a way to complicated way of checking if certain word from a list is in the message. How I see it, OP's code is much more efficient than this (although even that code can be optimized)

Comment: true this is a more complexed version of the blacklisted words, sorry for wasting ur time but i want to make it to where people can say **!settings blacklist on/off**